# Limit Points for a Set

Tags: real-analysis

I am new to real analysis and just got introduced to limit points.
There was one example I got stumbled upon that

If set $S=1,-1,1\frac{1}{2},-1\frac{1}{2},1\frac{1}{3},-1\frac{1}{3}.....$

Then 1 and -1 are the only limit points.

But I want to know why not anything else like

If we take 2 and

$ε = .5$

This give up neighborhood of 2 as
(2-ε,2+ε) which is

(2-0.5,2+0.5).

Then the neighborhood of 2 will have $1.5=1\frac{1}{2}\in S$

And $2\neq 1.5$

So why is 2 not a limit point ?

P.S.
Book's Definition
"If p is a real number then it will be said to be a limit point of any set S if there is at least one element q such that it belongs to set S as well as the neighborhood of p"

Comment: $1.5\notin S$. Anyway, consider $(1.9,2.1)$; that's a neighbourhood of $2$ with no elements of your sequence in.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why can't I take the ε .5 for the neighborhood ?

Comment: @AnswerSeekingPenguin A limit point of $S$ is a point $p$ such that *every* neighbourhood of $p$ contains a non-$p$ member of $S$. You can't just say "look, I found a neighbourhood which contains a non-$p$ member of $S$, so $p$ is a limit point!". You have to show that *every* neighbourhood works this way. Similarly, you can't say "hey, $15$ is prime, because I checked and it's not divisible by $2$!"; you have to check that *no smaller prime* divides $15$, not just that *some* smaller prime doesn't divide $15$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about the definition of "limit point". A point $p$ is a limit point of set $S$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a member of $S$ which is not $p$.

$2$ is not a limit point of your $S$, because the neighbourhood which is the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{3}$ around $2$ contains no members of $S$.

Comment: Oh so I have to consider every neighborhood of any point to be eligible for being limit point it means in case of 2, if epsilon is taken .5 then the set and neighborhood have a point in common but if epsilon is .1 then intersection of neighborhood and set is null and hence 2 is not a neighborhood.

Comment: @AnswerSeekingPenguin Yes.

Comment: @AnswerSeekingPenguin The set $S$ is not $(-1.5, 1.5)$. For example, it doesn't contain $1.41$. In fact it contains no points in $(1.38, 1.42)$; the nearest points it contains are $1.333\dots$ and $1.5$.

Answer (score 1):

The property in your PS must hold for every neighborhood. You cannot choose $\epsilon$ as you have done in 'showing' that 2 is a limit point.